# Required kernel modules / configuration for OTG host on OMAP3 based device

Tags: usb, kernel-modules, embedded, usb-otg

I'm trying to figure out what kernel modules that I need to load in order correctly configure an TI OMAP3 based device (DM3730) as a USB host via the on-chip OTG controller.

Without loading any additional USB/gadget modules the OTG host controller does not recognize any USB devices when they are attached (no output in kernel ring buffer). I can successfully get the controller working by loading the g_zero module, but as I understand it this is a device testing and debugging driver only.

What modules would I need to load instead in order to allow the device to be configured in host only mode?